# How can I display a line that has gone missing in a Highcharts graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use a Highcharts spline chart to plot temperature and dew point on the same chart. The color of the lines and points varies based on the values (red is hot and purple is cold with yellows and greens in between). Within the past few weeks, I noticed all of my temperature/dew point charts using this color scheme is only plotting the second parameter (dew point), although when mousing over where the temperature line should be displaying, the values are shown. I've been using this code within a PHP file for several years and haven't made any changes but the issue is affecting all charts on my website ([Willowsford Farm Weather example][1]) using this code - not just temperature and dew point. Is there a way to rectify this so that both lines are once again displayed? Here is the container code that displays a chart.

```
    <!-- Container code for Temperature extremes -->
<table>
    <div id="container1" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px"></div>

     <script language = "JavaScript">
     Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: '2023 Monthly Maximum and Minimum Temperatures'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Weather Station'
    },

    // Get data from the 2023 CSV file
    data: {
        csvURL: 'https://mywebsite.org/2023.csv',
        startColumn: 0,  // Start column has the dates
        endColumn: 2,  //End column is minimum temperature
        },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            colorByPoint: true
        },
        series: {   // series colors from purple (cold) to red (hot)
            zones: [{
                color: '#CC0066',
                value: -10
            }, {
                color: '#CC00CC',
                value: 0
            }, {
                color: '#6600CC',
                value: 10
            }, {
                color: '#0000CC',
                value: 20
            }, {
                color: '#0066CC',
                value: 30
            }, {
                color: '#00CCCC',
                value: 40
            }, {
                color: '#00CC66',
                value: 50
            }, {
                color: '#00CC00',
                value: 60
            }, {
                color: '#66CC00',
                value: 70
            }, {
                color: '#CCCC00',
                value: 80
            }, {
                color: '#CC6600',
                value: 90
            }, {
                color: '#CC0000',
                value: Number.MAX_VALUE
            }],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.B0f}'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
                text: 'Temperature (\xB0F)'
               },
            min: 0, // y-axis minimum value
            max: 110, // y-axis maximum value
            tickInterval: 10, // y-axis tick interval
            plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
               }]
    },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
               valueSuffix: '\xB0F', // display degrees Fahrenheit on the tooltip
               valueDecimals: 1 // display one decimal place on the tooltip 
            },
});
</script>
</table>


  [1]: https://novawx.dscloud.me/2023-wxrecords-highcharts.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because there is a bug in Highcharts v11.3.0 related to using zones with multiple series.

As a workaround use Highcharts v11.2.0: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3kL8n49m/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.2/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Or add the plugin from this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L4s0tm2h/

---

**Related issue:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20613